# Having trouble changing material alpha color in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to change a material alpha colour on runtime, but it isn't working.

Here is my script that changes the colour:

```
    public Material materialCol;
    public Color color;
    void Start()
    {
        color.a = PlayerTalents.talents_.sight;
        materialCol.SetColor("_Color",color);
    }
```

"color" is just white with alpha set to max

Here is the material setup:

[image: material set up]

Here is what it looks like in-game:

[image: in-game]

Here are the material properties of albedo in-game:

[image: material properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the value of `PlayerTalents.talents_.sight` is between 0 and 1f.
I've tested the code, this works:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class AlphaTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material materialCol;
    public Color color;
    void Start()
    {
        color.a = 0.7f;
        materialCol.SetColor("_Color", color);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes setting it to one float works, but i want it to be set to the value of a variable,  eg `color.a = f; /*(being the float)*/
materialCol.SetColor("_Color", color);
`

this gives the same end product as the image "in-game"

Comment: aha never mind, my float was over 1. I just needed to divide it by 100 (this is the max)